# How to make Apache Kafka available on both Localhost and a domain name

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having Apache Kafka installed on a Azure VM with zookeeper with following configuration

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://my.domain:9092
```

with this I am able to access the broker from external computers or even on local computer but with "my.domain:9092" if I try to do the same on local computer with "localhost:9092" or "127.0.0.1:9092" its refusing connections or not connecting .

I want to know what I am missing or any other config I need to change.
The zookeeper is on its default settings.
Any help is appreciated.

Following works fine

> ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list my.domain:9092 --topic
> TutorialTopic

Answer (score 0):

Those settings take a list of values. Simply add localhost to the advertised listeners

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

However, unless you're ssh'd to that machine, you actually need to run Kafka *on your local machine*, not a remote VM

Comment: Thanks for revert , I have some components directly connecting on the vfm itself , as far as adding local host is concerned it won’t let me add it unless the port is different .

Comment: That's correct. Listeners need different ports. If you're connecting a machine to itself, the route table shouldn't care if you use an external name vs localhost as they'd refer to the same machine